# How to find all element and text by using Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a Anchor tag(`<a>`) under the div class and under the `<a>` tag there is a `<p>` tag with the class and the `<p>` class matched with 12 item. I was trying to find all the text under the `p` tag using python.
Here is my code.
First approach:

```
for ele in  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="BrandCard___StyledP-sc-1kq2v0k-1 bAWFRI text-sm font-semibold text-center cursor-pointer"]'):
   print(ele.text)
```

Second approach:

```
content_blocks=driver.find(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.CategoryBrand__GridCategory-sc-17tjxen-0.PYjFK.my-4")
for block in content_blocks:
    elements = block.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for el in elements:
        list_of_hrefs.append(el.text)
```

but every time it gives me an error  `"WebElement is not iterable".`
I have added a picture of the page element.
[Page Element click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwUgT.jpg)

Comment: can you provide a link to that page?
and what exactly do you try to do with that element?

Comment: on your first approach, you miss the S(elementS), find_elements_by_xpath(..)

Comment: Here is the link:: https://evaly.com.bd/categories/speaker-2f615cf9a
On that page, there is some brand I am trying to find all the names from it. which is under a <p> tag.

Comment: @BUGGER check my answer, it should works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you, on your first approach you miss the S of elements (with S will return a list with all matches, without the first match).
I use xpath with contains some substring in the class.

```
r_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'BrandCard')]")
[x.text for x in r_elems]
```